# Javascript SharedWorkers demo to Typescript demo issues

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I created a simple demo of shared workers with plain JS and I decided to see if I could change it into a TS project and right from the start I've hit an issue and I'm not sure if it's to do with the the d.ts file or something else.

I've installed the @types/sharedworkers definition (npm install --save @types/sharedworker).
I'm using Typescript 2.1.1.

If I create a simple class such as

```
class MyTestClass {
    private worker : SharedWorker;
    constructor() {
        this.worker = new SharedWorker( 'JS_code_to_load');
    }
}
```

Then my IDE (IntelliJ) does the autocomplete for the import and makes it - 
*import SharedWorker = SharedWorker.SharedWorker;*

This seems to make sense from looking at the SharedWorker files - [Github sharedworker d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/sharedworker/index.d.ts)

But what happens is an error - TS2339: Property 'SharedWorker' does not exist on type '{ new (stringUrl: string, name?: string | undefined): SharedWorker; prototype SharedWorker; }'

Is this an issue with the the d.ts files, too many SharedWorker being declared (namespace, interface, & var)?

Should the import be different. Previous imports I've used have been for actual modules that I've imported, but the shared workers are not an external module that you install with npm.

Comment: Now that you solved the problem, could you please link to the demo result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on that type definition your code should be :

```
class MyTestClass {
    private worker : SharedWorker.SharedWorker;
    constructor() {
        this.worker = new SharedWorker( 'JS_code_to_load');
    }
}
```

Complete :

```
declare namespace SharedWorker {
    interface AbstractWorker extends EventTarget {
        onerror: (ev: ErrorEvent) => any;
    }

    export interface SharedWorker extends AbstractWorker {
        /**
         * the value it was assigned by the object's constructor.
         * It represents the MessagePort for communicating with the shared worker.
         * @type {MessagePort}
         */
        port: MessagePort;
    }
}

declare var SharedWorker: {
    prototype: SharedWorker.SharedWorker;
    /***
     *
     * @param {string} stringUrl    Pathname to JavaScript file
     * @param {string} name         Name of the worker to execute
     */
    new (stringUrl: string, name?: string): SharedWorker.SharedWorker;
};

class MyTestClass {
    private worker : SharedWorker.SharedWorker;
    constructor() {
        this.worker = new SharedWorker( 'JS_code_to_load');
    }
}
```